# Error responsive design, not showing fine on a phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a mobile/tablet website. I don't know why on my phone this thing happen:

[image]

But then.. when I open the sidebar:

[image]

I don't know why the body resizes itself. The `content` `<div>` moves to the right when the menu opens on the mobile. I want it to stay underneath the menu, so that the menu is on top of it.

Here's the HTML and CSS:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 overflow-y:hidden; 
}

#sidebar {
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#2a2a2a;
 border-right:1px solid #1d1d1d;
}

#sidebar ul {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#sidebar a {
 display:block;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:0px 10px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #1d1d1d;
 transition:all 0.3s;
 height:55px;
 line-height:55px;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
 background-color:#444;
}

#content {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#fff;
 transition:all 0.3s;
}

#menu {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:56px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
 line-height:56px;
}

#menu span {
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:30px;
 width:55px;
 height:56px;
 background-color:#445A87;
 color:#fff;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:56px;
}

.open {
 margin-left:251px;
}

#logo {
 position:absolute;
 right:50%;
 top:0px;
 margin-right:-80px;
 height:55px;
 width:160px;
 font-size:24px;
 color:#282828;
 background:url(../../img/Logo.png);
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Baby & Home · Servicio doméstico · Limpieza industrial<</title>
<link href="css/styles_min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
 <ul>
     <a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Quiénes somos</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Doméstico</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Industrial</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Promociones</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Ofertas de empleo</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Contacto</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="menu">
     <span id="open_sidebar" class="icon-list2"></span>
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#open_sidebar").click(function(){
 $("#content").toggleClass("open");
 if($("#open_sidebar").hasClass("icon-list2")) {
  $("#open_sidebar").removeClass("icon-list2");
  $("#open_sidebar").addClass("icon-cross");
 }
 else {
  $("#open_sidebar").addClass("icon-list2");
  $("#open_sidebar").removeClass("icon-cross");
 }
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

(I should say that in a web browser on a PC this works fine! Why not on a phone?)

Comment: this is not a bad thing. it's called responsive design!!! looks fine on my phone

Comment: Yes but when you click on the menu, looks horrible!

Comment: @serrguie - what screen size/sizes are the problem -  width 320px, 600px, or 800px? You can find out from http://quirktools.com/screenfly/
How would you like it to look? There is no background so I can't tell what the problem is. Is there is jsfiddle?

Comment: @Mousey I tried your tool, and everything's ok in web browser on a PC, but I try to access the website with my iPhone 5S and the body resize himself. What I am looking for is the contain div moves 251px from left side, and shows de sidebar, just that. Here's the link with your tool: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//babyandhome.es/tmob&w=320&h=568&a=37 Works great! But not on my phone.

Comment: I've edited your question to add the information and asked for it to be re-opened

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="content">` contains the images, and moves right, but you do not want it to. This is the cause of the layout problems.   The code which controls this is applied to **all* screen sizes but only looks bad on tiny ones:

```
.open {     margin-left:251px;}
```

You can delete this line to stop the `<div id="content">` moving 251px to the right - but the images and text would still be too big for the screen - and the menu would take up too much of the screen.

A better idea would be to make your code more **responsive**. Add this to your `CSS` - this will make the menu text and menu size smaller for screens 600px or less

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px)
  { 
 #sidebar {
         width: 150px; 
        margin:0; padding:0; 
        font-size: 12px; 
                } 
  }
```

This is called a **media query** and screens larger than 600px will stay the same. You can add to it, for example `line-height:1.1em` means each line is **1.1 characters wide**

[image]